# Binding to an object property in ViewModel, or how to use multiple models with the same property names

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to bind to a property of a Model via the ViewModel in an textbox. I created a wrapper in the ViewModel to access the property of the Model. Whenever I put a break point in the get section of this wrapper it triggers, but a break point in the set section is not executed after changing the textbox content. Code is according to the following tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193164/MVVM-Sample-application-with-a-focus-in-property

The BaseViewModel implements the INPC interface. I am trying to follow the MVVM "rule of thumbs" as close as possible. So no INPC implementation in the model in this case, and the view can only bind to the VM.

What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=ProgramInfo.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Model:

```
public class ProgramInfo 
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _description;
        
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get => _description;
            set
            {
                _description = value;
            }
        }
     
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
class ProgramInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ProgramInfo _programInfo;
        public ProgramInfo ProgramInfo
        {
            get => _programInfo;
            set
            {
                _programInfo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgramInfo");
            }
        }
    }
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ProgramInfoViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_programInfo is always null. you need to create an instance:

```
class ProgramInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ProgramInfo _programInfo = new ProgramInfo();
    public ProgramInfo ProgramInfo
    {
        get => _programInfo;
        set
        {
            _programInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProgramInfo");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ProgramInfoViewModel { ProgramInfo = new ProgramInfo() };
    }
}
```

---

a view model wrapper for model property will look like this:

```
class ProgramInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ProgramInfo _programInfo;

    private ProgramInfoViewModel(ProgramInfo programInfo)
    {
        _programInfo = programInfo;
    }

    public string ProgramInfoName
    {
        get => _programInfo.Name;
        set
        {
            _programInfo.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProgramInfoName");
        }
    }
}
```

initialization:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var model = new ProgramInfo();
        DataContext = new ProgramInfoViewModel(model);
    }
}
```

binding path has to change accordingly:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ProgramInfoName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This still doesn't trigger the break point in the set command when I change the textbox value in the GUI.

Comment: I set the breakpoint in the wrapper on the ViewModel. On the OnPropertyChanged() call to be specific. If I set it in the Name {set } it will trigger when I change the text. It seems like the view is directly bound to the Model for the set command, but not for the get command?

Comment: ProgramInfo setter will not be triggered by binding. Binding source is Name property in ProgramInfo class. Put breakpoint in Name {set } to check. ProgramInfo setter can be triggered by assignment, like this: ` DataContext =  new ProgramInfoViewModel { ProgramInfo = new ProgramInfo() };`

Comment: that makes sense. But that means the view can edit the Model data directly, which is not according to MVVM right? How could I solve this?

Comment: your edit works like a charm. I decided to create the ProgramInfo instance in the VM, to prevent a reference to the model in the code-behind. It would have been a great feature to nest properties like I tried to do, but I guess that where Fody.Weaves comes into play. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @cherryPicker There is nothing wrong with a view that directly displays or modifies a model property. It's still MVVM.

Comment: @Clemens As for all the information I found on MVVM, especially the diagrams, there is no direct link between the View and the Model.